# how to append only 1 time with a loop

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to check if a value exist inside an array and if it does not exist then i want to append my value to my container but i only want it to append 1 time.

```
var getWords = $("#input").val();

if (getWords)
{

    //this is my array
var check_Key_Value = $(this).parent().parent(".main-rating-container").find(".key-words-style").map(function()
        {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();

    for (var i = 0; i < check_Key_Value.length; i++)
    {
        if (check_Key_Value[i] != getWords)
        {
            //This is gonna append as many time as the length of my array how do i only append 1 time?
            $(".container").append('<p class="key-words-style">'+getWords+'</p>');
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use inArray instead of the for loop

```
var getWords = $("#input").val();

    if (getWords)
    {

        //this is my array
    var check_Key_Value = $(this).parent().parent(".main-rating-container").find(".key-words-style").map(function()
            {
                return $(this).text();
            }).get();

       if($.inArray(getWords,check_Key_Value) == -1)
    {
     $(".container").append('<p class="key-words-style">'+getWords+'</p>');
    }
    }
```

More about inArray here https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Answer (score 0):

Invert your search.  Look for the value.  If it exists, stop and do nothing else.  If you make it to the end of the array without finding it, append it to the list.

```
var getWords = $("#input").val();

if (getWords) {

  //this is my array
  var check_Key_Value = $(this).parent().parent(".main-rating-container").find(".key-words-style").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();

  // store whether we have found the value 
  var hasValue = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < check_Key_Value.length; i++) {
    if (check_Key_Value[i] == getWords) {
      // value found, stop
      hasValue = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  // if we didn't find it in the loop, add it
  if(!hasValue) {
      $(".container").append('<p class="key-words-style">' + getWords + '</p>');
  }
}
```

To simplify further, you can use `indexOf` or `inArray` which will essentially do the search for you.

Answer (score 0):

After you append, the next line should be `return false;`
This will break the loop from running again.